# How to play AudioStream with multiple audio inputs sequentially?

Tags: sound

I have around 10 music files in a directory and I load them as AudioStream as shown:

```
dir = SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
files = FileNames["*.mp3",dir];
stream = AudioStream[Audio[#]]& /@ files;
```

The variable `stream` is now a list of 10 AudioStream. Now when I play it using AudioPlay

```
AudioPlay[stream]
```

All the AudioStream start playing simultaneously.

How do I make them play one by one, automatically when one gets over the next one should start, as well as manually, like having a button which when clicked would play the next audio on the list?

Answer (score 1):

You were very close, but you are creating multiple `AudioStream`'s. Instead you can create a single `AudioStream` which can play multiple files one after another:

```
dir = SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
files = FileNames["*.mp3",dir];
stream = AudioStream[Audio /@ files];

AudioPlay[stream]
```